# File write issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the following code.  It does not generate an error but my file does not get updated either.

```
if([cDate  compare:Today] == NSOrderedAscending){

     NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, 0", Today]);
     if(![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, 0", Today] writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE])
            NSLog(@"writeToFile failed");  
}
```

Comment: Where is filePath pointing to? It needs to be a writable directory such as the Documents directory - not the app bundle.

Comment: So we can presume that the outer if is true?  The first NSLog is written?

Comment: The filepath is set as: NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"txt"];  and yes I assumed if the method returns a true, the file is written.  Is that a wrong assumption?

Comment: I should add that I can read this file without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to the Bundle. it's code signed and read-only. You need to use the documents folder.

use this to get to the document folder and you chave write permissions there.

```
NSArray *basePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```